# Public domain app to send files to trash in OS X

Tags: macos, license, trash, licensing

Is there any Public Domain (using [the unlicense](http://unlicense.org/) or something similar, not really relevant) app that sends files to the trash in OS X? There are a bunch of alternatives to this ([example](http://hasseg.org/trash/)), but I need a public domain one (since it’ll serve as a small part of a much bigger public domain app).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
mv dumb_file ~/.Trash
```

Comment: No good. That moves it to the trash, yes, but it doesn’t give me all the goodies (i.e., you can’t use “Put Back” to send it to the original location).

Answer (score 0):

please correct me if i'm wronf.

as far as i understand you'd like to have some kind of a undo function so you can restore files but not like the finder integrated version wich does it with a per Partition/Disk way than with a centralized Directory.

so why don't you just move it to a self chosen separate directory and log (e.g. in a txt file in this separate folder) where the file originally was.

Comment: No, what I want is for it to work exactly like the Finder integrated version. That app I liked to (and many others) do exactly that, but you can call them from a script or from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an AppleScript like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run a
    set l to {}
    repeat with f in a
        set end of l to POSIX file f
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder"
        move l to trash
    end tell
end run
```

It doesn't work with relative paths though.

Comment: “It doesn't work with relative paths though”. Then it’s not the same, unfortunately.